# Aren't Low Quality Posts review audits too easy to spot?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I just met this review audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3354165

[image: Obvious review audit]

Wow, that's difficult to miss. You can see the high score of the answer, as well as the author's rep which is higher than 100k.

However, I remember that the review audits in the Close Votes review queue will "anonymize" the vote count and the author so that it can catch robo-reviewers more easily. More specifically, the vote count is replaced with a `0` instead of the original high score, and the user's name and reputation count is replaced so it is more obscure.

Why isn't this the case for the Low Quality Posts review audits? Shouldn't this be applied as well?

Comment: Frankly, I want it that way.

Comment: They aren't supposed to be hard to spot, just ensure a bare minimum of paying attention

Comment: The number one consideration for review audits is to minimize "false negatives", by which I mean that non-robotic reviewers should have an easy time avoiding "STOP! Look and listen!"

Comment: @devnull No I don't think that is a duplicate. That question appears to be asked during early times of the review queue and users still didn't know about review audits, but this one is about something else